# JMeter Script issue

Tags: jmeter

I am new to `JMeter`. I have taken up `HP webtour(127.0.0.1/WebTours)` for practicing.

I recorded a scenario for flight booking. I correlated the session ids and found the script was working fine( i was able to see correct HTML pages in View Result Tree).

So, ideally if i run the script a flight should be booked and when i check the application manually i should see a flight but this isn't happening. I run the script,it goes fine but i dont see a flight booked. I have tried to correlate dynamic values and don't see any pending value which isn't been handled.

Any idea on this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you double check the post request were the flight is booked. Because JMeter will put a green if it gets a response with status 200, but it is our responsibly to make sure that we have got the appropriate page. 'Response Assertion' can help you in doing it.